# Set HTML Page background image using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to set page backgroudImage using jQuery.
I wrote this code but it is not work.
What is the problem?
Image is exist
[image]

```
var Page = $(this);
$(function () {
    SetBackgroundImage();
});


function SetBackgroundImage() {
    //Todo read ImagePath from server

    var ImageUrl;
    ImageUrl ="../Images/BackgroudImage.jpg";

    try {

        Page.css('background-image', 'url(' + ImageUrl + ')');
    } catch (e) {
        //LogError
        alert(e.Description);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `Page` currently holds a reference to a jQuery object which is wrappend around the `window` element. You'll want the jQuery object to wrap around the `body` tag.

To retrieve the body element you'll have to adjust your code a bit, like so:

```
$(function() {
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + ImageUrl + ')');
});
```

I suggest you take a look at the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com) for some more information about jQuery.